# how can we compile and run multiple .h and .cpp and one main.cpp file together

Tags: c++, vector

I have created a Card.h file having a class card, I need this Class in Deck.cpp. The class Deck is needed in Hand class Implementation.
These are the files

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include<utility>
class Card{
// a card have a suit and a rank
// we can create a pair of string
public:
    std::pair<std::string,std::string> card ;    
public:
Card(){

}
Card(std::string r, std::string s){
    card = std::make_pair(s,r);
}
};
 class Deck{
// we can create a vector of Card type
public:
    vector<Card> deck;
public: 
Deck();
};
class Hand{
//this class will hold what card a players get
vector<Card> hand; // it will have 5 cards
public:
    Hand();
    Hand(Deck cards,int start,int end);
    void displayHand();
};


#endif
```

Deck.cpp

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<chrono>
#include "card.h"
using namespace std;
class Deck{
    // we can create a vector of Card type
    public:
        vector<Card> deck;
    public: 
    Deck(){
        string suits[4] = {"hearts","spade","clubes","diamonds"};
        string rank[14] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Joker","Queen","King","Ace"};
        for( int  i =0 ; i<4 ; i++){
            for(int j =0 ;j<14;j++){
                Card temp(suits[i],rank[j]); // using the constructor function 
                deck.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
        //after taking all values we need to shuffle the elements of our vector
        // for this what one can do is to 
        // run a loop through our vector deck generate a random number between 0 and 52-1 and swap the ith element with that random index
        // here I am using the built in shuffle function in C++
        unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now()
                        .time_since_epoch()
                        .count();
        shuffle(deck.begin(),deck.end(),default_random_engine(seed));
        
    }
};
```

Hand.cpp file

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include"card.h"
using namespace std;
class Hand{

    //this class will hold what card a players get
    vector<Card> hand; // it will have 5 cards
    public:
        Hand(){

        }
        Hand(Deck cards,int start,int end){ // we will slice 5 cards from Deck of cards and give it here
            for(int i = start ; i< end ;i++){
                hand.push_back(cards.deck[i]);
            }
        }
        void displayHand(){
            for(int  i = 0 ; i< hand.size() ; i++){
                cout<<hand[i].card.first <<" "<<hand[i].card.second<<endl;
            }
        }
};
```

Main.cpp file

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<utility>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include"card.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Deck d;
    Hand p1(d,0,5);
    Hand p2(d,5,10);
    Hand p3(d,10,15);
    Hand p4(d,15,20);
    Hand p5(d,20,25);
    p1.displayHand();
    p2.displayHand();
    p3.displayHand();
    p4.displayHand();
    p5.displayHand();

}
```

I know that the best practice is to use .h files for classes. But I want to know how we can do this in this way.
for compiling I am using g++ *.cpp -o program

---

and it is giving me the following errors

```
    In file included from deck.cpp:5:
    card.h:20:9: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
    20 |         vector<Card> deck;
        |         ^~~~~~
    card.h:27:5: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
    27 |     vector<Card> hand; // it will have 5 cards
        |     ^~~~~~
    deck.cpp:7:11: error: redefinition of ‘class Deck’
        7 |     class Deck{
        |           ^~~~
    In file included from deck.cpp:5:
    card.h:17:8: note: previous definition of ‘class Deck’
    17 |  class Deck{
        |        ^~~~
    In file included from hand.cpp:4:
    card.h:20:9: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
    20 |         vector<Card> deck;
        |         ^~~~~~
    card.h:27:5: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
    27 |     vector<Card> hand; // it will have 5 cards
        |     ^~~~~~
    hand.cpp:6:11: error: redefinition of ‘class Hand’
        6 |     class Hand{
        |           ^~~~
    In file included from hand.cpp:4:
    card.h:24:7: note: previous definition of ‘class Hand’
    24 | class Hand{
        |       ^~~~
    In file included from main.cpp:5:
    card.h:20:9: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
    20 |         vector<Card> deck;
        |         ^~~~~~
    card.h:27:5: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
    27 |     vector<Card> hand; // it will have 5 cards
        |     ^~~~~~
```

Comment: -> `std::vector`, `#include <vector>`

Comment: Your card.h is missing "using namespace std", so it cannot determine what "vector" is. Either use std::vector, or add "using namespace std". (better always use std namespace (std::vector, std::map) to avoid future collisions)

Comment: @holmes0: but `using namespace` should be avoided especially in header.

Comment: @Jarod42 should be, but not must be, added recommendation to comment

Comment: Your implementation of class in cpp file is also wrong.

Comment: If you deadly want to avoid declaring classes in headers, you could use modules of C++20.

Comment: #include "Deck.cpp" file will do the job ?

Comment: thanku @et11enne I add #include "deck.cpp" inside hand.cpp file and include hand.cpp inside main file. I also remove the class definitions of Deck and Hand I added previously in card.h file.